Issue when using multiple solidify modifiers
I am having an issue when using multiple solidify modifiers.
I had a path imported from Inkscape representing the 2d surface covering of a skull. I converted into a mesh and then build faces and subdividing it to have a more defined mesh.
Then since my goal is to reproduce the human skin, I subdivided the mesh in several vertex groups (17) and assigned a solidifier modifier to each of them (simple mode, 0 offeset, all thicknesses are between 0.9 and 2 millimeters).
It works until the last 2 modifiers (by works I mean it is possible to switch to object mode from edit mode), but then when I add the last two and try to go object mode the program crashes.
Do you have any idea of which could be the problem? If this is not a suitable way would you suggest another one still giving precision in the results?
Thank you very much for your help!
